# Why can't I use QRCodeReader class in ZXing(installed with CocoaPods) in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, zxing, qr-code, cocoapods

I am using cocoapods to install ZXing 2.1, and my Podfile content is as follows:

```
platform :ios, '5.0'                                                                                                                                                 
pod 'ZXing/ios', '~> 2.1'
```

everything is right, I can import use `#import <TwoDDecoderResult.h>` to use `TwoDDecoderResult` class , but I can not use `QRCodeReader` class however, although I have imported `#import <QRCodeReader.h>`
why ?

Comment: iostream.h file not found and some undefined symbol problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is I can not use QRCodeReader class in my X.m file. Xcode will complain that `iostream.h file not found` and some link error of `undefined symbol of ... avm7s'(something like that). Additionally, my cocoapods is 0.25.0(where you must first see the changelog [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0250) and my Xcode is 4.6.3

After searching, I have solved my problem as follows:

1. change my X.m file to X.mm file suffix . That is because my X.mm file wants to use QRCodeReader that is originally C++ class in ZXing
2. set your project & target build setting: `"Build Valid Architecture Only"` flag to be `NO`. Repeat this step to your pods project & target, too.
3. In **main** project -> Build Settings scroll and find out the options, C++ Language Dialect and C++ Standard Library. Select options "Compiler Default" for both of them. (This is the step I missed, It is needed because newest XCode template has compiler default settings different to what they were in older versions).

now build & run, It will be ok.